# Prohobit type usage across default or not AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, appdomain, trace

Is it possible to somehow prevent a type usage across an AppDomain (preferably in default)?

Clarification: I want to an exception (preferably compiler error) occurs on some type usage / instantiation / member access. I want to prohobit a direct usage of `EventLog` in favour of `TraceSource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get compile time error for classes loaded into an AppDomain since AppDomains are runtime concept. I don't know about run-tim way.

I would not recommned even trying to block usage of system classes like EventLog - you never know what other libraries use.

As an option you can do compile time check of your code to prohibit function calls (i.e. by using custom FXCop rule). You can also do similar check at run time for assemblies you are loading, also you will need to write more infrastructure to do so.

Comment: Yea, sure - either on compile check, or AppDomain

Comment: It's possible in compile time if we assume he is talking about his code (as it seems), not any referenced assembly or run-time loaded library (i.e, using reflection). The product would be a kind of `visual studio plugin`. A macro can do the job with limitations.